# LocationListener onLocationChanged doesnt occur

Tags: android, android-studio, locationlistener

Hello I have class that is supposed to get current users location using LocationListener

```
public class GpsSender {
 static Context ctx;
 static LocationManager lm;
 static Location location;
 static double longitude;
 static double latitude;
 static LocationListener locationListener;

 public GpsSender(Context ctx) {
     this.ctx = ctx;
     lm = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     locationListener = new LocationListener() {
         public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
             Log.i("LocationListener","Location changed!");
             longitude = location.getLongitude();
             latitude = location.getLatitude();
         }

         @Override
         public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
         }

         @Override
         public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
         }

         @Override
         public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
         }
     };

     lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
 }

 static public void printLoc() {
     Log.i("TEST", "lat:"+latitude+" lon:"+longitude);
 }
}
```

It works on emulator whem i set lat lon through console, but when I try it on real device, the lat lon is 0.00 all the time. The onLocationChanged, doesnt even occur.

Comment: This event only occurs if the location actually changes. Have you tried moving the device a couple of meters?

Comment: Do you have a GPS lock?  Acquiring a GPS signal takes time, and frequently doesn't work indoors.  I'd recommend using an app like GPS Test to see the state of your GPS.